# Getting the path of a node module in a view

Tags: node.js, npm, video.js

I'm a beginner using NodeJS. I'm using a plugin for `video-js` called `videojs-playlist`. The docs say to include it like this:

```
<script src="path/to/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/videojs-playlist/dist/videojs-playlist.js"></script>
```

What exactly is the `path/to` supposed to be if not `root/node_modules` or something like that? How am I supposed to access those files from an ejs view? I have installed both `video-js` and `videojs-playlist` using npm.

Right now I get redirect errors on my page because it's not finding the file from the paths I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path doesn't have a `/` at the beginning, then the path is relative to the file the `<script>` tag is in; otherwise, it is relative to the site root -- which may mean different things depending on if/how you are bundling/deploying your javascript.

For a simple case, if you have the script tags in an `index.html`, and you copied `video.js` to the same directory as `index.html`, you would reference by:

`<script src="video.js">`

If you are using Node to test things out on your personal machine, you could reference a file relative to your HTML file and `node_modules` directory; however, this wouldn't really be the best in the context of deploying and managing a real application.

Node gives you [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) to import modules from dependencies you've installed without needing to specify their exact location and directory structure, but it looks like this particular plugin may not have given you that convenience here.

It looks like you are in need of a bundler. One widely-used and well-documented bundler is [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), but there are others such as [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) and [FuseBox](https://fuse-box.org/). These can all serve your needs.

These tools are most likely what the `videojs-playlist` [README on GitHub](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist) is referring to when they say:

> Include videojs-playlist on your website using the **tool(s)** of your choice.

Among other features, these tools can take a file from one of your `node_modules` dependencies, and "bundle" relative your javascript application (however you desire), so that you don't have to carry around some pre-installed giant `node_modules` directory everywhere with you -- you only take what you need with you and structure it the way you want.